# how to get threaddump from core dump with wait thread info

Tags: thread-dump

I'm using java 1.6 on solaris machine.

I used the following command to get threaddump from a core file `/usr/java/bin/jstack -J-d64 /usr/java/bin/java core`

I got the following output, which shows the thread is in state of `BLOCKED`, but it does not show what thread it is waiting.

```
Thread t@165517: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await() @bci=8, line=416   (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run() @bci=11, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=662 (Interpreted frame)


Thread t@165516: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await() @bci=8, line=416     (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run() @bci=11, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=662 (Interpreted frame)
```

how do I get thread dump from a core file with output format like

```
daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000100d4cc00 nid=0x4576 in Object.wait() [0xfffffffd35cff000..0xfffffffd35cff640]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0xfffffffd70277c58> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:416)
        - locked <0xfffffffd70277c58> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:442)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Thanks, Helen